# What's the error-correcting capacity (randomly errors, or burst errors) of polar code?

Tags: coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

[Polar codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_code_(coding_theory)), invented by [Arikan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3917.pdf), with low encoding and decoding complexity. But the minimum distance of polar codes is not great. The normalized minimum distance goes to 0 with the block size. Yet, the existing decoding algorithms for polar codes can asymptotically achieve channel capacity.

Generally, a code with minimum distance $d$ can correct $\frac{d-1}{2}$ errors (random errors). And Polar code is also error-correcting code, I was wondering how many errors can it correct( e.g. A $[2048, 614]$ with $BEC(0.19)$ polar code.)? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but I think you may be asking the wrong question. Polar codes don't have a meaningful "error correction capability" obtainable as in algebraic codes by (d-1)/2. Alternatively, this is not the meaningful parameter of significance.

For finite lengths their performance is usually analyzed in BEC (Binary Erasure Channel) and AWGN channels (Additive White Gaussian Noise). The well-cited paper *On Finite-Length Performance of Polar Codes: Stopping Sets, Error Floor, and Concatenated Design* by A. Eslami and H. Pishro-Niki on arxiv [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2187.pdf) as well as some more recent papers confirm this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind reply, Let me check the reference. Thanks.